# Chrome extension event listener causes Bootstrap 3 nav menu unclickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, event-handling

is there a work around to disable chrome extension from registering its listener? I have tested with Bootstrap Navbar testing page at https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/.

Prior that, I have installed an chrome extension, and that is called Web Page Sticky Note at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-page-sticky-notes/alpjieidnmmkljnceakgpeajlngabnee/support.

As I know, jquery library should be loaded before bootstrap.js (correct me if wrong). In my case, the jquery (version 1.11.3) is loaded after the bootstrap.js loaded, check the attached image at the bottom. This situation causes the chrome extension event overwriting the bootstrap events, and thus causing un-clickable nav menu dropdown.

I am not sure if this is a problem with the chrome extension or my own application javascript event handling. Additionally, is that illegal for a chrome app or extension for using jquery (3rd party libraries)?

Suggestions are desperately needed, I appreciate your time for some sharing.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to disable your chrome extension and reload the page to check if the dropdown still not workable. If it works after disable the extension, it means the js injected by the plugin crash the code.

And it is not illegal to use 3rd party library in the chrome app/extension if the usage follows the license terms.